# JQuery multiple colors in 1 cell from a value

Tags: jquery, gridview, pivot-table

I have a ASP.NET Pivot Table and in the cells of that table there are various values 1, 2, 3 or 4. Whichever value is selected turns the cell to one of four colours.

```
$(function () {

        var colors = { 1: 'green', 2: 'orange', 3: 'red', 4: 'blue' };
        $("td").css('background-color', function (index, value) {
            var txt = $(this).text();
            if (colors.hasOwnProperty(txt)) {
                $(this).html('&nbsp;') 
                return colors[txt];
            }
            return value;
        });

    });
```

In basic theory this code works fine, however, what i would like to do is, instead of the entire table cell turning a certain colour i would like part of the table cell to turn into a certain colour in accordance to a single value from my database!

At present if there are 3 records in the one cell  (lets say 3, 2, 4) then instead of the figures being seperate and the cell output being in 3 parts,  red, orange and blue they add up (9) and no colour value is added at all.

Comment: How would the same effect be achieved using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of HTML architechture. You can divide the cell by using a `span` for each number, and apply the colors to the spans instead of the whole `TD`

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTFvm/1/)

HTML :

```
<td>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </td>​
```

CSS:

```
span {
display:block;
    float:left;
}​
```

JS:

```
  var colors = ['green','orange','red','blue'];
$("span").each(function(){
             col = parseInt($(this).text());
                $(this).css('background-color', colors[col-1]);

});
```

Comment: Little unsure what you mean! Can you quantify your comment with a code snippet? Again this is JQuery

Comment: Probably need to mention that the initial code works with a a gridview which source is generated through a datatable. Bit more complex than just HTMLtable.

Comment: you can still manipulate the output with JS to match the aforementioned structure

Comment: i still can't see how you would manipulate this method provided which would enable part of the table cell to turn into a certain colour in accordance to a single value from my database! I don't see how the span can be added to the Gridview (datasorse datatable)

Comment: Okay seems the trail has gone cold! Can anybody tell me how to seperate the values in each cell then. At present the seperate values are adding up and making a whole number. If i keep them seperate then that may help me achieve my goal!